# Cross-platform method for finding python include folder

Tags: python

I have python extension code that I need to cross-platform compile, and to do so, I need to be able to find the python include folder.  On Linux and Mac OSX, I can do `python-config --include` and it gives me something like `-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.3/include/python2.6`.  This is fine and dandy, except that my Windows python distro doesn't have `python-config`.  Is there an easy way, through python code, of finding where it thinks the include folder is?  For `numpy`, this snippet does the job:

```
try:
    numpy_include = numpy.get_include()
except AttributeError:
    numpy_include = numpy.get_numpy_include()
```

Is there an analogous method for the python include folder?

Comment: I don't think there's any way of finding the actual include folder. I think you'll just have to see if python-config exists, and if not make a guess with as many different path names you can think of :|.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> from distutils import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_python_inc()
'/usr/include/python2.6'
>>> sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=True)
'/usr/include/python2.6'
```

Note: I found this out by looking at `python-config` source.

Comment: And in Python 2.7 and 3.2, `sysconfig` has been expanded and generalized into its own module in the standard library, independent of `distutils`:  http://docs.python.org/library/sysconfig.html, for example, `sysconfig.get_path('include')`